# select one row from nested table type

Tags: sql, oracle, nested-table

my question is there away to select only one record from that column type as default value.

[image]

```
create type t_tel as table of number;

create table users_tel(
user_id number,
user_name varchar2(100),
tel t_tel
) nested table tel store as tel_table;

insert into users_tel(user_id, user_name, tel) values (1, 'Amir', t_tel(987,654,321));

select * from users_tel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a table collection expression to treat the collection in the nested table as if it was a table and join on that. Then you can filter to get one row per `user_id`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c5df/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create type t_tel as table of number;

create table users_tel(
  user_id number,
  user_name varchar2(100),
  tel t_tel
) nested table tel store as tel_table;

insert into users_tel(user_id, user_name, tel)
  SELECT 1, 'Amir',  t_tel(987,654,321) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Dave',  t_tel(123,456)     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Kevin', t_tel()            FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT user_id,
       user_name,
       tel_no
FROM   (
  SELECT u.*,
         t.column_value AS tel_no,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY u.user_id ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   users_tel u
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         TABLE( u.tel ) t
         ON ( 1 = 1 )
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c5df/4/0)**:

```
| USER_ID | USER_NAME | TEL_NO |
|---------|-----------|--------|
|       1 |      Amir |    987 |
|       2 |      Dave |    123 |
|       3 |     Kevin | (null) |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **group by** to do it:

`select u.user_id, u.user_name, min(t.column_value) def_tel 
 from users_tel u
 left join table(u.tel) t on 1=1
 group by u.user_id, u.user_name;`

Note that i am using **left join** with the table Type to show records where `tel` is null.